# Random integer in a certain range excluding one number

Tags: javascript, random

I would like get a random number in a range excluding one number (e.g. from 1 to 1000 exclude 577). I searched for a solution, but never solved my issue.

I want something like:

```
Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 1).exclude(577);
```

I would like to avoid `for` loops creating an array as much as possible, because the length is always different (sometimes 1 to 10000, sometimes 685 to 888555444, etc), and the process of generating it could take too much time.

I already tried:

- [Javascript - Generating Random numbers in a Range, excluding certain numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19451425/javascript-generating-random-numbers-in-a-range-excluding-certain-numbers)
- [How can I generate a random number within a range but exclude some?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5520835/how-can-i-generate-a-random-number-within-a-range-but-exclude-some)

How could I achieve this?

Comment: I don't understand the problem you're having and why the solutions you posted don't work for you. Wouldn't a simple while loop that checks for the forbidden number be sufficient?

Comment: Get a random number from 1 to 99999, if the number is >= 577, then add 1.

Comment: @ebyrob ok but if is 99999 the number and i add 1 it make an error because 10000 not exsist. I dont want create "if" condition

Comment: @j08691: yes i would like is it possible without loop?

Comment: But logically, a loop makes the most sense. Get a random number, does this number equal the forbidden number? If so, then get a new random number. Unless you're randomly picking from something like an array that doesn't contain the forbidden number to start with, then you're forced to check on every pick.

Comment: So generate the number, if it is in that list, generate a new one, continue until you have one. I highly doubt it will keep generating 557....

Comment: @P.Frank So go to 99998.  (multiply by 99999 instead of 100000)

Comment: Thank you all for your help.

Comment: This QA **makes me physically sick**.  I am **disgusted** that I live in the same universe as this QA.  The only answer is Marco's http://stackoverflow.com/a/34184614/294884

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The fastest way to obtain a random integer number in a certain range `[a, b]`, excluding *one* value `c`, is to generate it between `a` and `b-1`, and then increment it by one if it's higher than or equal to `c`.

Here's a working function:

```
function randomExcluded(min, max, excluded) {
    var n = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max-min) + min);
    if (n >= excluded) n++;
    return n;
}
```

This solution only has a [complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity) of O(1).

Comment: yes is fine but n++ get not random number but random + 1

Comment: @P.Frank That's the trick! For example assume you want it from 1 to 10, but not 5. You generate it from 1 to 9, then, if it is higher than or equal to 5, you add 1. Doing this you can only obtain [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], which is what you want. All the numbers have the same probability to be generated, and 5 will never be generated.

Comment: I have choose your solution, but the solution of @guest271314 is too good for me. thank you

Comment: What if i wanted to pass an array of numbers(any size)..say 5,6 & 7 to be excluded? How would I approach this?

Comment: Why is the greater than important? Why can't we increment the random number only if n=excluded? @MarcoBonelli

Comment: @Chirag if you do that you will never get the maximum value.

Answer (score 5):

One possibility is not to add 1, and if that number comes out, you assign the last possible value.

For example:

```
var result = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100000));
if(result==577) result = 100000;
```

In this way, you will not need to re-launch the random method, but is repeated. And meets the objective of being a random.

Comment: This also seems to work.  Not sure assignment is any faster than addition but nice twist.  Why the down vote?  I think for multiple exclusions this would actually be faster.  (and not require sorting)

Comment: this is the only correct algorithm, but Marco's version below is more elegant.

Answer (score 3):

As @ebyrob suggested, you can create a function that makes a mapping from a smaller set to the larger set with excluded values by adding 1 for each value that it is larger than or equal to:

```
// min - integer
// max - integer
// exclusions - array of integers
//            - must contain unique integers between min & max
function RandomNumber(min, max, exclusions) {
    // As @Fabian pointed out, sorting is necessary 
    // We use concat to avoid mutating the original array
    // See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9592740/how-can-you-sort-an-array-without-mutating-the-original-array
    var exclusionsSorted = exclusions.concat().sort(function(a, b) {
        return a - b
    });

    var logicalMax = max - exclusionsSorted.length;
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (logicalMax - min + 1)) + min;

    for(var i = 0; i < exclusionsSorted.length; i++) {
        if (randomNumber >= exclusionsSorted[i]) {
            randomNumber++;
        }
    }

    return randomNumber;
}
```

[**Example Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/019vq5gd/14/)

Also, I think @JesusCuesta's answer provides [a simpler mapping](http://jsfiddle.net/019vq5gd/13/) and is better.

**Update:** My original answer had *many* issues with it.

Comment: Yep, the logical conclusion, loop on the smaller set.

Comment: @Fabian Thank you for pointing that out. I updated the function accordingly.

Comment: This is too great for me. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could just continue generating the number until you find it suits your needs:

```
function randomExcluded(start, end, excluded) {
    var n = excluded
    while (n == excluded)
        n = Math.floor((Math.random() * (end-start+1) + start));
    return n;
}

myRandom = randomExcluded(1, 10000, 577);
```

By the way this is not the best solution at all, look at [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34184614/3889449) for a better one!

Comment: This has infinite slowdown potential.

Comment: Yeah, if you think about it mathematically, but since that JS can generate thousands of randoms in a microsecond, this is never going to be slow.

Comment: **very surprisingly you would suggest this Marco, given you know the correct answer below.  should be deleted.**

Comment: @JoeBlow this is still an answer, and there's no need to delete it because it answers the question properly, like many others do

Answer (score 1):

To expand on @Jesus Cuesta's answer:

```
function RandomNumber(min, max, exclusions) {
    var hash = new Object();
    for(var i = 0; i < exclusions.length; ++i ) {  // TODO: run only once as setup
       hash[exclusions[i]] = i + max - exclusions.length;
    }
    var randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * (max - min - exclusions.length)) + min);
    if (hash.hasOwnProperty(randomNumber)) {
       randomNumber = hash[randomNumber];
    }
    return randomNumber;
}
```

Note: This only works if max - exclusions.length > maximum exclusion.  So close.

Answer (score 0):

Generate a random number and if it matches the excluded number then add another random number(-20 to 20)

```
var max = 99999, min = 1, exclude = 577;
var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min ;
while(num == exclude || num > max || num < min ) {
    var rand = Math.random() > .5 ? -20 : 20 ;
    num += Math.floor((Math.random() * (rand));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

def rng_generator():
  a = random.randint(0, 100)
  if a == 577:
    rng_generator()
  else:
    print(a)

#main()
rng_generator()
```

Answer (score -2):

Exclude the number from calculations:

```js
function toggleRand() {
  // demonstration code only.
  // this algorithm does NOT produce random numbers.
  // return `0` - `576` , `578` - `n`  
  return [Math.floor((Math.random() * 576) + 1)
          ,Math.floor(Math.random() * (100000 - 578) + 1)
         ]
         // select "random" index 
         [Math.random() > .5 ? 0 : 1];
}

console.log(toggleRand());
```

---

Alternatively, use `String.prototype.replace()` with `RegExp` `/^(577)$/` to match number that should be excluded from result; replace with another random number in range `[0-99]` utilizing `new Date().getTime()`, `isNaN()` and `String.prototype.slice()`

```js
console.log(
  +String(Math.floor(Math.random()*(578 - 575) + 575))
  .replace(/^(577)$/,String(isNaN("$1")&&new Date().getTime()).slice(-2))
);
```

---

Could also use `String.prototype.match()` to filter results:

```js
console.log(
  +String(Math.floor(Math.random()*10)) 
  .replace(/^(5)$/,String(isNaN("$1")&&new Date().getTime()).match(/[^5]/g).slice(-1)[0])
);
```

Comment: Certainly an interesting solution, might hurt the random distribution though.

Comment: this is not the intended random distribution. The first time it's called, it only returns a number < 576.

Comment: @Fabian Could  use `Math.random() > .5 ? 0 : 1` to select random index between `0` , `1` to return

Comment: yes, but e. g. 100 would have a higher probabolity than 900. I don't think that's what we want

Comment: @Fabian _"100 would have a higher probabolity than 900"_ ? What are 100 and 900 referencing ? Probability of what ?

Comment: Thank you man is the best way for me (without loop). Great job!

Comment: **This solution is very bad**! Splitting the range in two, and then looking on the first or the second part based on `Math.random() > .5 ? 0 : 1` will **NOT** generate pure random numbers, as the probability of obtaining each number is not equal. Take for example: `[Math.floor((Math.random() * 1) + 1), Math.floor(Math.random() * (100000 - 3 + 1))][Math.random() > .5 ? 0 : 1]`: it will generate `1` in 50% of the cases.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli _"will NOT generate pure random numbers"_ Does `Math.random()` generate "pure random numbers" ?

Comment: @guest271314 as I said, look for example at `[Math.floor((Math.random() * 1) + 1), Math.floor(Math.random() * (100000 - 3 + 1))][Math.random() > .5 ? 0 : 1]`. The result would be 1 50% of the times, even though you are chosing a random number in the range [1, 100000].

Comment: @MarcoBonelli _"it will generate 1 in 50% of the cases"_ Yes, this is expected; though not in a linear sequence. Does `Math.random()` generate "pure random numbers" ?

Comment: @guest271314 I don't really think that getting 1 as result 50% of the times is the expected behavior if you want "a random number between 1 and 100000".

Comment: @MarcoBonelli Perhaps there should be a clear definition of "random" ? From what able to grasp, here, `Math.random()` does not generate "pure random numbers"

Comment: @MarcoBonelli Also, if call `Math.random()` 100 times the result will not be 50% 1 : 50% 0

Comment: @guest271314 of course, 100 are too few, it would take infinite tests to round up the value to 50%...

Comment: is the best way for me, but have you a solution for have not 50% 1?

Comment: @guest271314 I think it's very hard to misconstrue the interpretation of random in this question as anything other than an equal opportunity of each number being picked (or as close as possible).

Comment: @MarcoBonelli _"of course, 100 are too few, it would take **infinite** tests to round up the value to 50%..."_ Yes, this is correct. If required infinity to determine result, result cannot be determined accurately. _"it will generate 1 in 50% of the cases"_ cannot be proven

Comment: @P.Frank _"is the best way for me, but have you a solution for have not 50% 1?"_ "50% 1" is not correct, cannot be proven.

Comment: @P.Frank Try at `console` 1 or 100 times `var res = [];
for (var i = 0; i< 100; i++) {
  res.push(Math.random() > .5 ? 0 : 1)
}; var n = res.filter(function(n) {
  return n === 1
}); console.log(n.length)` . Observe how many times `n` `.length` is exactly `50`

Comment: @P.Frank I added another answer, check it [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34182699/random-number-exclude-one/34184614#answer-34184614).

Comment: Waoow very nice! The snippet does'nt work because the result is frequently 575 or 576 (more than 50%). Your first script `+String(Math.floor(Math.random()*1000))
 .replace(/^(577)$/,String(isNaN("$1")&&new Date().getTime()).slice(-2))` is so brilliant! Now if i have 10 number and i used your script `+String(Math.floor(Math.random()*10))
 .replace(/^(5)$/,String(isNaN("$1")&&new Date().getTime()).slice(-2))` i have result bigger 10. Please test `for(t=1;t<10;t++){
console.log(+String(Math.floor(Math.random()*10))
 .replace(/^(5)$/,String(isNaN("$1")&&new Date().getTime()).slice(-2)))
 }` why?

Comment: @P.Frank `.slice(-2)` was used to meet requirement at Question , [0-576,578-1000] . Could substitue another string filter, for example, using `.match()` .See updated post `+String(Math.floor(Math.random()*10)) 
            .replace(/^(5)$/,String(isNaN("$1")&&new Date().getTime()).match(/[^5]/))`

Comment: @JoeBlow _"this is incredibly wrong"_ What is "this" ? What is "incredibly wrong" ?

Comment: It simply ***does not*** generate random numbers.  It's really a shame when non-mathematicians just make totally wild guesses at things like this: the problem is, this utter nonsense will now be seen on the internet for 1000 years. The poster here should just *click delete* for goodness sake.  Note that this is a RIDICULOUSLY well-known problem in comp sci and the solution is absolutely trivial.  Here's a full, long-winded explanation with source code http://stackoverflow.com/a/35315960/294884  Also the correct answer is given below at http://stackoverflow.com/a/34184614/294884

Comment: It's just so embarrassing -- the poster here's other comments (on "pure" random numbers etc.) unfortunately indicate simply no knowledge of the field in question.  Anyway. That's the internet.

Comment: @JoeBlow _"It simply does not generate random numbers."_ Which version ?

Comment: The fact that this answer is ticked makes me **physically ill**.  This QA is **disgusting**.