# Typescript/Javascript: Replace All String Occurrences with Random Number

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following function that replaces a string occurence with a random number.  What I have currently replaces the string with the same random number.  I need a function that replaces each instance a unique number. Here's what I have.

Attempt to Clarify:

I want to find all occurrences of `'},{` and replace it with `},"random":{` where `random` is a unique integer for each occurrence.

```
result = this.replaceAll(result, '},{', `},"${this.getRandomInt(1, 2000)}":{`);

private getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

private replaceAll(str, find, replace) {
  return str.replace(new RegExp(this.escapeRegExp(find), 'g'), replace);
}

private escapeRegExp(str) {
  return str.replace(/([.*+?^=!:${}()|\[\]\/\\])/g, "\\$1");
}
```

Currently the result is something to the effect of

```
},"1340":{"expense_category_id":"63","amount":3},"1340":{"expense_category_id":"62","amount":3}}}}
```

1340 should not have duplicated

Edit: The value of result before replace all is:

```
},{"expense_category_id":"63","amount":3},{"expense_category_id":"62","amount":3}}}}
```

Comment: What is `result` before you call `replaceAll()`?

Comment: Do not replace. Split the input by `}, {`, then re-join it by `}, number:{`, replacing the `number` every time in a loop.

Comment: You can generate `N` unique numbers, one for each `RegExp` match, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/40063045/

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown I edited my answer to show value of result before

Comment: @ctilley79 Ok, i've added your input string into my code. It seems to work well.

Comment: Both of the answers are right.  What do I do? lol

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pass a function to the `replace()` second parameter like this:

```js
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

function replaceAll(str, find, replace) {
  return str.replace(new RegExp(this.escapeRegExp(find), 'g'), replace);
}

function escapeRegExp(str) {
  return str.replace(/([.*+?^=!:${}()|\[\]\/\\])/g, "\\$1");
}

var input = '},{"expense_category_id":"63","amount":3},{"expense_category_id":"62","amount":3}}}}',
    result = replaceAll(input, '},{', (x => '},"' + getRandomInt(1, 2000) + '":{'));

console.log(result);
```

I'm not sure why, but it seems that it uses the same string generated for the first iteration for subsequent iterations. With a function, you force it to run everytime.

Answer (score 1):

Your replace call is wrong.  You're passing in a string, you should be p[assing in a function that creates the number](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=let%20result%20%3D%20%22%7BA%7D%2C%7BB%7D%2C%7BC%7D%22%3B%0D%0Aresult%20%3D%20replaceAll(result%2C%20'%7D%2C%7B'%2C%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20return%20%60%7D%2C%22%24%7Bthis.getRandomInt(1%2C%202000)%7D%22%3A%7B%60%20%7D)%3B%0D%0Aalert(result)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20getRandomInt(min%2C%20max)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20return%20Math.floor(Math.random()%20*%20(max%20-%20min%20%2B%201))%20%2B%20min%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20replaceAll(str%2C%20find%2C%20replace)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20return%20str.replace(new%20RegExp(this.escapeRegExp(find)%2C%20'g')%2C%20replace)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20escapeRegExp(str)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20return%20str.replace(%2F(%5B.*%2B%3F%5E%3D!%3A%24%7B%7D()%7C%5C%5B%5C%5D%5C%2F%5C%5C%5D)%2Fg%2C%20%22%5C%5C%241%22)%3B%0D%0A%7D), not the result of the number itself.

```js
    let result = "{A},{B},{C}";
    result = replaceAll(result, '},{', () => { return `},"${this.getRandomInt(1, 2000)}":{` });
    console.log(result);
    
    function getRandomInt(min, max) {
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    }
    
    function replaceAll(str, find, replace) {
      return str.replace(new RegExp(this.escapeRegExp(find), 'g'), replace);
    }
    
    function escapeRegExp(str) {
      return str.replace(/([.*+?^=!:${}()|\[\]\/\\])/g, "\\$1");
    }
```

Comment: Cool. I see what you mean now.  I'm going to fiddle around with this.