# For every x in string replace with random result

Tags: javascript

I need to replace thousands of `#FFF` instances in the string via

```
Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16)
```

The problem I ran into is that I'm unable to make JS to run this command for each `#FFF` in the string, instead, it replaces all `#FFF` to a single result.

```
var string = '1677px 335px #FFF , 59px 1161px #FFF , 850px 963px #46f3b8';
var randomColor = string.replace(/#FFF/g, "#"+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16));
console.log(randomColor);
```

results in something like:

```
1677px 335px #46f3b8 , 59px 1161px #46f3b8 , 850px 963px #46f3b8
```

Comment: Use a [callback function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Using_an_inline_function_that_modifies_the_matched_characters) instead of a value for the replacement argument

Comment: `.replace(/#FFF/g, ()=>"#"+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16))`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript/Javascript: Replace All String Occurrences with Random Number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43504533/typescript-javascript-replace-all-string-occurrences-with-random-number)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, that in your code,

```
'#' + Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16)
```

is evaluated once, then its result string is passed to `replace`, and it replaces all occurrences of `#FFF` with that string.

Instead, you can use a function as a replacer, that is called *for each* match and can generate different values:

```js
var string = '1677px 335px #FFF , 59px 1161px #FFF , 850px 963px #46f3b8';
var randomColor = string.replace(/#FFF/g, () => '#' + Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16));
console.log(randomColor);
```

Answer (score 2):

I like the approach of splitting your string, then iterating and joining together using unique values:

```js
var string = '1677px 335px #FFF , 59px 1161px #FFF , 850px 963px #FFF , 333px 496px #FFF , 704px 507px #FFF';
var parts = string.split("#FFF");
var output = parts[0];
for (i=1; i < parts.length; ++i) {
    output += "#" + Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16) + parts[i];
}
console.log(string);
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason this is better than the `.replace` one?

Comment: No.  It's just a different way of expression that some people might prefer.  Using split and join to delimit and generate strings is a common operation, so it meshes well with manipulation of a list of style color codes to generate a string well logically.  FYI this code could be done with one line with chained manipulation in a way that is much easier to read IMO.  `split.map(x=>random).join` would IMO far more concise and clear than this simple concat loop.  But that's a matter of opinion.