# Unique random number generator in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, random

I have this code but I do not know how to do it so that I do not repeat numbers

example:
2433,1150 ---> this is the code

```
Model.prototype.number_rand = function(){
    var number =  Math.floor(1000 + Math.random() * 9000)
    console.log(number)
    return number
}
```

Comment: Only way to know would be to keep track.... If it was generated before than you repeat....

Comment: you may have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40056297/1447675