# How to prevent repeating numbers in Math.random() javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following code (see below) in a HTML file that generates random numbers between the range 100000-999999 (It works fine) but I want to make sure it does not REPEAT itself. How do I modify it or add code to do that?

```js
       
 
var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*999999) + 100000
document.write(randomnumber)
```

Comment: so you do not want to get a random number twice?

Comment: it will write itself once Bud. No worries

Comment: Do you want just prevent in same request or unique for other request?

Comment: no it is not. Please stop marking duplicates

Comment: you might have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40056297/random-number-which-is-not-equal-to-the-previous-number

Comment: @messerbill yes, i don't want a random number twice.

Comment: @GrahamJansen have a look at Faly's answer

Comment: Your code doesn't produce the range you want.

Answer (score 3):

You can keep track of all numbers that are already used:

```
var numbers = [];
var randomnumber;
do {
    randomnumber= Math.floor(Math.random()*999999) + 100000;
} while (numbers.includes(randomnumber));
numbers.push(randomnumber);     
document.write(randomnumber)
```

If ES6 is a problem (`array.prototype.includes`), you can use `array.prototype.indexOf` :

```
// ...
do {
    randomnumber= Math.floor(Math.random()*999999) + 100000;
} while (numbers.indexOf(randomnumber) !== -1);
// ...
```

Comment: you were too fast :D nice solution

Comment: A better solution would be to use `numbers.indexOf(randomnumber) !== -1` since that doesn't require the runtime to implement ES 2016.