# Math.random() call number only one time

Tags: javascript

So as my question is how to call random number, but only 10 times (when we got numbers from 0 to 9) with different numbers. 
here is code for generate random number:

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
```

but that code for example can get number 2, two times.

example output: 4, 3, 2, 9, 4, 3, 6, 3;

How to get output like that: 5, 3, 6, 4, 1, 9, 8, 2;

Here is a function:[fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/4vs7phje/12/): but, numbers are random and can repeat and going over and over.

So how to replace number when number already exist, and stop variable from calling when all numbers was used?!

Comment: Where is fiddle?

Comment: Looks like you just want numbers from [1, 10) shuffled?

Comment: Forget the fiddle. Put a [mcve] **in the question**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380019/generate-unique-random-numbers-between-1-and-100

Comment: this may help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40056297/random-number-which-is-not-equal-to-the-previous-number

Comment: see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6274339/how-can-i-shuffle-an-array

Answer (score 2):

Sounds to me like you don't really want a series of random numbers, you want to randomly shuffle a series of non-random numbers. Here's how I'd do it:

```
var nums = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
for(var i = nums.length; i > 0; i--) {
    var temp = nums[i - 1];
    var swapIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * i);
    nums[i - 1] = nums[swapIndex];
    nums[swapIndex] = temp;
}
```

Comment: I have 23 divs.  And I need to animated them 1 by one only 1 time becouse they are going in to 3d perspectove. But thanks anyway.

Comment: @PiotrMirosz This is the answer you seek.  What (if anything) is not working for you?

Comment: i think i'm not able to use your answer. Not working for me, but maybe will work for someone.

Comment: i going to make another question, i'm not going to change that one when answers was correct.

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this

```
var limit = 10;
var results = []

function randomGenerator () {
    while (results.length < (limit -1)) {
      var generated = Math.ceil(Math.random() * limit);
      if (results.indexOf(generated) < 0) {
          results.push(generated)
      }
  }
}

randomGenerator()
alert(results)
```

Comment: Goes into infinite loop.

Comment: No it doesn't https://jsfiddle.net/Lq4v4s1L/6/