# How to save randomly generated numbers to a txt?

Tags: javascript, html

And how would I keep a list of the last 5 numbers generated?
 How should I apply this function in the following code?

`<button onclick="document.body.innerHTML += (Math.floor(Math.random() * ( 989000000 - 988000000 ) + 987000000 ) + '<br>' );">Gerar Números</button><br>`

Comment: have you had a look here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40056297/random-number-which-is-not-equal-to-the-previous-number

Comment: Yes, I had but is not what I am looking for but thank you a lot :)

Comment: Are you trying to save the numbers to a txt file? Or are you trying to make an array? Your question and goal is unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to use only js I found this to [create a file with js](http://jsfiddle.net/UselessCode/qm5AG/)
then I edited the script for your purpose, see the result:

```js
    let i=0;
    let offset=-5;
    let values="";
    let $list = $("#list");

    function generateRandom() {

        var ran = Math.floor(Math.random() * ( 989000000 - 988000000 ) + 987000000 );
        //textArea.value += ran + "\n";
        values += ran +"\n";

        $list.prepend('<li id="' + i++ + '">' + ran + '</li>');

        if(offset>=0){
            $("#" + offset).remove();
        }
        offset++;

    }

    (function () {
        var textFile = null,
            makeTextFile = function (text) {
                var data = new Blob([text], {type: 'text/plain'});

                // If we are replacing a previously generated file we need to
                // manually revoke the object URL to avoid memory leaks.
                if (textFile !== null) {
                    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(textFile);
                }

                textFile = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);

                return textFile;
            };


        var create = document.getElementById('create');

        create.addEventListener('click', function () {
            var link = document.getElementById('downloadlink');
            link.href = makeTextFile(values);
            link.style.display = 'block';
        }, false);
    })();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="generateRandom()">Gerar Números</button>
<ul id="list"></ul>
<button id="create">Create file</button>
<a download="info.txt" id="downloadlink" style="display: none">Download</a>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!
This is exactly what I was needing. It may not be possible to save the information of the last 5 numbers generated in the html but I thank you very much for your help. Your help was perfect.